# Can one pass a parametrized class as parameter to another that would be derived by another

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

First parametrized class

```
template<typename T>
class elements
{
    protected:
        int e,f;
    public:
        elements(){}
        elements(int ee):e(ee){}
        const elements& operator=(const elements& other)
        {
            e = other.e; return *this;
        }

};
```

The base class

```
template<typename T>
class list
{
    protected:
        T item;
};
```

Finally the class in contention

```
template<typename T>
class row:public list<elements<T> >
{
    public:
        row(int a)
        {
            item;
        }
};
```

if the parameter is specified as int, list etc. Then the program runs else I keep getting the error
'item' was not declared in this scope,

I can't seem to get to work and would appreciate if someone could help me understand how it works.

Thanks

Comment: what is the point of `element` being a template? It does not use `T`

Comment: please post a full program that demonstrates the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the correct scope:

```
template<typename T>
class row:public list<elements<T> >
{
    public:
        row(int a)
        {
            list<elements<T> >::item;
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
};
```

See [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53fc490ddba916ad)

Comment: very cool, they both work: https://godbolt.org/g/Pc8oLn

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the compiler doesn't know what `item` is.   Depending on what `T` is, it could be a type, a variable.  Because it can't tell without more information, it checks to see if it's something immediately available without the templated information and because it's not, the compiler has to give up.

By saying `this->item` instead of just `item`, you are very clearly telling the compiler that item is a variable.

The answer in the question linked in the comments is quite good and worth a read.

As you can see here, both `this->` and the class scope both work:  https://godbolt.org/g/Pc8oLn